# what means about "-DSTM32F10X_MD -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER" as the flags of arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: gcc, makefile, stm32, stm32f1

they seems like startup and standard files of stm32 ,but i can not find them in "GCC offical refeence PDF" .

why can they be used directly

this is the  flags of arm-none-eabi-gcc in makefile:

```
# specify compiler flags
CFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall
CFLAGS += -T$(STD_PERIPH_LIBS)/Project/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Template/TrueSTUDIO/STM3210B-EVAL/stm32_flash.ld
CFLAGS += -mlittle-endian -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb-interwork
CFLAGS += -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
CFLAGS += -DSTM32F10X_MD -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER
CFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections
CFLAGS += -I.
CFLAGS += -I$(STD_PERIPH_LIBS)/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/DeviceSupport/ST/STM32F10x/
CFLAGS += -I$(STD_PERIPH_LIBS)/Libraries/CMSIS/CM3/CoreSupport
CFLAGS += -I$(STD_PERIPH_LIBS)/Libraries/STM32F10x_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-D` is a [preprocessor flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) passed to GCC to define something before compilation. It can be used to enable certain functions of libraries or even debugging.

`STM32F10X_MD` and `USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER` enable parts of the included library. It being the STM32F10 part of the library for medium density devices and enabling the usage of standard peripheral library.

*Please note that the SPL isn't supported anymore and that you should upgrade to the HAL or HAL LL.*

Comment: I see. Thank you！ ：）

Answer (score 0):

it's library specific flags (in this case STM32F10x Standard Peripherals Library)

[documentation link](http://www.longlandclan.yi.org/~stuartl/stm32f10x_stdperiph_lib_um/Library_Use.html)

[or look for official documentation](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-stm32054.html)

Answer (score 0):

`-Dsomething` is the same as `#define something` in the source code.